# Asynchronously updating ListFragment

Tags: android, asynchronous, fragment, android-listfragment

I've checked other answers regarding the asynchronous updates of `ListFragments` and have figured out that the most common problem for the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method not working is, that developers tend to overwrite the initial adapter source, causing the adapter to lose reference and hence not updating the view. I have a `ListFragment` that I want to update asynchronously. What I've decided to do, is parse the list data in an `AsyncTask` and finally update the fragment in `onPostExecute()`. I want the UI to be as fluid as possible, so I want to avoid doing heavy processing on the main thread. I call the `AsyncTask` after the views are created to avoid `null` pointers.

```
public class CategoryFragment extends ListFragment {

ArrayList<Category> categoriesArray = new ArrayList<Category>();
CategoryAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
            adapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.category_list_item, categoriesArray);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    new UpdateUITask().execute(categories);
}

...

    // The async task to update the UI.
class UpdateUITask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Category>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Category> doInBackground(String... input) {

        // Do some data processing, to fill the categoriesArray.
        // categoriesArray.add(...); -- loop
        return categoriesArray;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Category> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

The refresh method fires, but produces no result. What else am I missing here? Should I pick a completely different approach?

Comment: which type of adapter are you using, is it ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: It's a custom adapter. If it is relevant I'll be glad to post some code of the adapter as well.

Comment: no just make sure that you are creating customer adapter by extending ArrayAdapter, otherwise your notifyDataSerChanged will not work.

Comment: and also, categoriesArray list object set to adapter should not change, just add,remove or update objects in the that same categoriesArray list.

Comment: I only do categoriesArray.clear() and categoriesArray.add(). I suppose that is ok in terms of preserving the data object reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looking like your instance of categoriesArray is getting lost.   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't work only in case when your refrence of the listArray which you just passed to the adapter has been lost or changed. So, I would reccomend you to please make sure about this.

Also if you are going to populate your custom array then, use `onProgressUpdate() method` of the `AsyncTask`. It will reduce the loading time too.
You can do this like this:

```
class UpdateUITask extends AsyncTask<String, Category, ArrayList<Category>>
    {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Category> doInBackground(String... input)
        {

            // Do some data processing, to fill the categoriesArray.
                    //  and get the category objects one by one and call  
                    //publishprogress till data is there
            publishProgress(Category);

                    // and finallly just return somthing to get in onpostexecute

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Category... values)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    categoriesArray.add(...);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Category> result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code for your AsyncTask, but please make sure again you are changing in the original categoryList.

```
private class UpdateUITask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do some data processing, to fill the categoriesArray.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and just run this task with passing any argument.

```
new UpdateUITask().execute();
```